# Issue regarding C# collection performance

Tags: c#

My application contains **two** observable collections:

**1**

```
int count = collection.Count();
```

It takes nearly 30 milliseconds.
Please tell me any method which should take very less time.

**2**

I am comparing `collection_1` with `collection_2` with specified value
like:

```
var common = collection_2.firstOrDefault(i=>i.name == collection_1.name);
```

It takes more than 6 milliseconds where `collection_1` contains more than 35,0000 records and `collection_2` contains ore than 1,00,000 records. Please tell me the best way.

my code:

```
foreach (var singleItem in StartWindow.omsReqRes.Where(i => i.Tag.Contains("Request")))
{
    AddFileData(singleItem);
}

public void AddFileData(LogClass singleItem)
{
    var responses = (StartWindow.omsReqRes.Where(i => i.Clordid == singleItem.Clordid && i.Tag.Contains("Response")));
    foreach (var response in responses)
    {
        LogClass obj = new LogClass();
        obj.AlgoName = singleItem.AlgoName;
        obj.RealTime = singleItem.RealTime;
        obj.TimeStamp = singleItem.TimeStamp;
        var request = StartWindow.gatewayReqRes.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Tag == singleItem.Tag && i.Clordid == singleItem.Clordid);
        if (request != null)
            obj.v = request.e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code please...

Comment: foreach (var singleItem in StartWindow.omsReqRes.Where(i => i.Tag.Contains("Request")))
                { AddFileData(singleItem); }

Comment: That is not enough, please edit your entire relevant code into your post. We need to at least know the type of the collection and how it is used. We can't gues what your code looks like.https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i am unable to post my code it is showing too long characters

Comment: I doubt that using `Enumerable.Count` lasts 30 milliseconds. Since its a collection it will simply use that property. But you could also do it yourself by removing `()`, so use `int count = collection.Count;`

Comment: provide the real (compiling) code, this is clearly not: `var common = collection_2.firstOrDefault(i=>i.name == collection_1.name);
`

Comment: i need to find the count of enumerable only, if i convert enumerable to list, then it takes 27 milliseconds

Comment: I have added my code to my question

Comment: May be you need to try this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Is `Clordid` a unique ID? If it is, maybe you can create a Dictionary once at startup with this ID as key. Dictionary lookup should be much faster than searching in a list or array - O(1) vs O(n).

Comment: Clordid is not unique here

Answer (score 0):

The collection contains more than 1 lakh records, so it takes more time for searching, I divided collection based on one value to key value pair dictionary
hence it takes less time